# Set icon to JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, imageicon

I've tried the code below.

```
try {
        this.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("/resources/dbs.ico")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Alsow I've tried the code given below.

```
yourFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(Filepath)));
```

Also I've tried the code given below.

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/some/package/favicon.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

But none of all these solution is working.
The directory structure is :

/pro_root/com/girishpro/multirecharge/resources/dbs.ico

Also I've tried below.

/pro_root/resources/dbs.ico

The dbs.ico is the image which I want to set as Icon for JFrame. Please help me for solving this problem.

Comment: The last attempt with getResource seems most adequate, and should work. Only caveats: filenames are case-sensitive in a jar, and `getClass()` must be in the same jar (mind child classes). Check with 7zip or so in the jar the correct path.

Comment: I've tried as you said, no any exception occurs and no image is displayed as icon!

Comment: I normally do it so, in the JFrame child constructor, before `frame.setVisible(true);`. As you do not get a NullPointerException, the icon was loaded. Maybe you later call an other `setIconImage/setIconImages`; unlikely.

Comment: There is no any exception (like NullPointerException or FileNotFoundException) occurs, but also Image is not displayed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()` for an array of file types that the Java run-time can read.  It might appear like this (actual example for this machine right now):

```
type: bmp
type: jpg
type: wbmp
type: jpeg
type: png
type: gif
```

Nope. No `ico` type.

Comment: Worked it out, thank you very much. Now got it that .ico is partially/not supported to java. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

as the answer is given [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460050/set-icon-to-jframe/30461296#30461296). In java, .ico is partially or not supported. So to everyone who is finding correct solution, please ensure that for icon, you are not using .ico file for icon. Thanks to [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson)

Comment: The only types you can actually rely on Java to support are `jpg`, `png` & `gif`.  I'd use one of the last two for frame icons since they support transparency.

Answer (score 0):

According to your structure the dbs.ico is placed in the root together with packages of your classes.

So the code should work

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dbs.ico"))
```

Comment: Could you check classes in the target dir? Can you find the .icon file there? May be your build process just skips the .ico type of resources.

Comment: I've checked src and bin folder of eclipse project, and also I've checked .jar file by using WinRar, the .ico file exist there with proper path.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and verify the path of the image according to the class of the JFrame.

```
        try {
            SetIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/image.ico")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```